# How do I populate a DataRow and assign it to one of two tables based on a condition?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow, datarowcollection

I have data being processed by an app which needs to sort the data based on whether or not a bit is flipped.   The tables **are identical**.  The code as it stands looks something like this:

```
DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

DataRow r = dt1.NewRow();
FillUp(ref r);

if(bitISetEarlier)
   dt2.ImportRow(r);
else
   dt1.ImportRow(r);
```

Now, a clear problem I was having is that if the row wasn't already attached to a table, `ImportRow()` fails silently and I end up with an empty table.   When I changed this to:

```
    if(bitISetEarlier)
       dt2.Rows.Add(r);
    else
       dt1.Rows.Add(r);
```

I started getting an exception saying that a function was trying to add a row that existed for another table.   So when I tried this:

```
if(bitISetEarlier)
    if(r.RowState == DataRowState.Detached) 
         dt2.Rows.Add(r) 
    else dt2.ImportRow(r);
 else
     if(r.RowState == DataRowState.Detached) 
          dt1.Rows.Add(r) 
     else dt1.ImportRow(r);
```

the exception stopped, but any attempt to assign to `dt2` still states that the row belongs to another table, but if I comment out the `dt2` `if` statement and just attempt `ImportRow()`, the `dt2.Rows.Count` remains at 0 and no records assigned.

I need to populate the `DataRow` before knowing which table it belongs in, but I have no idea what columns the row will have before it hits this function.  The condition that indicates which table it should go to is *not* stored with the data in the `DataTable`.

Is the problem that even though they have identical columns, `NewRow()` is adding an attribute to the row that makes it incompatible with the sister table? Is there a way I can get the same functionality as `NewRow()` (copy schema without knowing what any of the columns are ahead of time) but that I can dynamically assign?  I'm aware I could probably manually construct a row that is compatible with either by wrapping it in a `for` loop and building out the columns every time i need the new row using the `DataTable.Columns` property, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: Figure out which table *first* then create the NewRow from that table...or add the data directly.  `dt1.NewRow()` creates a new row for dt1.  Trying to add it to dt2 will be...problematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.   Since I can't add the row built off of one table to the other table directly, I figured it was the `DataRow` object that was problematic, but the  `ItemArray` property was probably all I needed.

```
                    if (isErrorRow)
                    {                           
                        //nr is the NewRow for dt1
                        var nr2 = dt2.NewRow();
                        nr2.ItemArray = nr.ItemArray;
                        dt2.Rows.Add(nr2);
                    }
```

This effectively cloned the rows.